# Duda con import/export

Tags: javascript

Tengo un `selector` en el html, con 3 `options`.

```
    <select>
        <option selected disabled>SELECT</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
```

En el archivo.js principal, cuando elijo una opción u otra del html, manda el número asociado con export:

**archivo-principal.js**

```
export let slc = selectEx();

function selectEx(){
    document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change',function(){
        return parseInt(this.value);
    });
}
```

Habiendo seleccionado ya una de las `option`, lo que quiero hacer es que, según qué `option` elija, ejecute un archivo.js u otro. Ya que mando el resultado por el `export` y en cada archvo.js tendría un `import`.

**archivo1.js**

```
import {slc} from 'path';

    if(slc == 1){
        ...codigo...
    }
```

**archivo2.js**

```
import {slc} from 'path';

    if(slc == 2){
        ...codigo...
    }
```

Y así sucesivamente. El problema es que, slc, en los otros archivos no se está leyendo. Asumo que lo estoy haciendo al revés, pero lo que pretendía hacer era ahorrar mucho código en el js principal.

¿Cómo podría enfocarlo correctamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo conseguí:

1. Importar todos los elementos primero
2. Obtener el resultado del select
3. Hacer un switch, y llamar a la función segun el case

```
selectEx();

function selectEx(){
    document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change',function(){
        switch(parseInt(this.value)){
            case 1:
                u01();
                break;
            case 2:
                console.log('usar variable Y');
                break;
            case 3:
                console.log('usar variable Z');
                break;
        }
    });
}
```